# Can Stored Proc parameter types reference the type of a column on a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, schema

If I have a Product table with ID, Desc and I change Desc from 100 to 200 chars, I need to update the parameters in all Stored Procs that reference the column.

Is it possible for a stored proc parameter type to 'refer' to the type defined by a column in a table?

Something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]
(
    @id     NUMERIC(10,0),
    @desc   Product.Desc.Type
)
```

Comment: I guess you want `%TYPE` from Oracle. See [connect1](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/534711/t-sql-t-sql-type-inference-) and [connect2](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/506542/t-sql-t-sql-type-inference%20howeve). Simply: No

Comment: No this is not possible. You can do it in Oracle but not SQL Server.

Comment: Yes,  I thought I'd done it in Oracle. Seems like a sensible thing to include in SQL Server!